# how to use session inside groovy thread

Tags: grails, groovy

I am new to Groovy. I want to update session variables inside a Groovy thread. 
I can't put real code so I am putting sample code.

```
public updatename()
    {
        println(session["firstname"]);
        Thread.start
        {
                session["firstname"] = "atul";
                println(session["firstname"]);         
        }
    }
```

I am able to access session variable outside of thread, but I am getting the following error for session inside thread

> "Error java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found:
>   Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web
>   request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving
>   thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still
>   receive this message, your code is probably running outside of
>   DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request."

Any idea how can i use session variable inside thread

Comment: I guess you are trying this in controller which I do not think would work according to the error message which is pretty much lucid. Instead you can move that logic to service and try. I would rather suggest you use [Executor plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/executor) to implement what you are trying to achieve with Thread.

Comment: thank you dmahapatro. i will look into the link you provided

Comment: @dmahapatro, I had used executor plugin and found the same issue while using Tag libs in separate thread, I resolved it by making simple DTO's and pass that to the asynch block.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can only access the session from within the scope of a web request handling thread, because you need the request context to know *which* session to use.  A reference to the `session` property in a Grails controller is actually a Groovy-style call to a `getSession()` method injected into the class by Grails that dynamically fetches the correct session from the current request.

It may be possible to store a reference to this session in a local variable in the controller action, and then refer to that variable within the `Thread.start` closure:

```
public updatename()
{
    println(session["firstname"]);
    def theSession = session
    Thread.start
    {
            theSession["firstname"] = "atul";
            println(theSession["firstname"]);         
    }
}
```

but I haven't tried this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following in web.xml

```
<web-app ...>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

And it not works, you can make a simple DTO (POJO) and pass that to thread.